# Angular 6 - Export SVG from DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg, download

I am rendering a SVG element into the DOM with D3.js and want the user to be able to download that generated file.

The easiest way is to use the [SVG Crowbar](https://github.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar), but I really want that feature in my application. You can have a look on my application, if it helps you understand my problem: [Angular 6 - D3js - Application](https://github.com/nextlevelshit/nls-ng6-d3js-guilloche)

If you do not know any node package, that I could use for that, please consider to give me some advice how to build such module to distribute it for the rest of the world.

Comment: Thanks, that solution is vanilla JS, right? Do you think it would be helpful to write a small node module? @barbsan

Comment: Yes, all those solutions are in vanilla JS, just browser support is required but `XMLSerializer` is well supported even on mobile devices.

Comment: I will try that solution and will mark it as dupe in case.